# Rails sublayout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a Messages controller, with actions like: `Sent messages`,`Received messages`,`Send new message`. They are displayed to the user in a toolbar form. The thing is, when I render each view, I have to manually render the toolbar as well. So, here's how the code for the views looks like:

```
sent_messages.html.erb
   <%= render "shared/toolbar" %>
   #  render stuff for sent messages


received_messages.html.erb
   <%= render "shared/toolbar" %>
   # render stuff for received messages


new.html.erb
   <%= render "shared/toolbar" %>
   # render stuff for new message
```

The views don't look very DRY. Is there a way I could specify that I want the `toolbar` to render before everything else, in the Messages controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts):

Suppose you have the following ApplicationController layout:

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @page_title or "Page Title" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "layout" %>
  <style><%= yield :stylesheets %></style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top_menu">Top menu items here</div>
  <div id="menu">Menu items here</div>
  <div id="content"><%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On pages generated by NewsController, you want to hide the top menu and add a right menu:

`app/views/layouts/news.html.erb`

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  #top_menu {display: none}
  #right_menu {float: right; background-color: yellow; color: black}
<% end %>
<% content_for :content do %>
  <div id="right_menu">Right menu items here</div>
  <%= content_for?(:news_content) ? yield(:news_content) : yield %>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

That's it. The News views will use the new layout, hiding the top menu and adding a new right menu inside the "content" div.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged

Answer (score 0):

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"><%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/views/layouts/messages.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :content do %>
  <%= render "shared/toolbar" %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
<%= render file: "layouts/application" %>
```